# How to create a line and rotate around its center using only css

Tags: css

I am beginner of CSS. I have found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32560509/3617261. But i want to learn that if it is possible to rotate the created line with only using CSS, without using JavaScript.

Comment: Please, provide the code for us to see where you tried doing that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS [animation](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/) like this :

```css
.line {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  margin:100px;
  background: #000;
  animation:rotation 10s linear infinite; /* run the rotation for 10s and iterate again */
  transform-origin:center; /* rotate from the center */
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg); /* start from 0 degree */
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) /* end at 360 degree which the same as 0 degree to create the continuous loop*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform to rotate to a specific position.

```
transform: rotate(40deg);
transform-origin: center;
```

For animating, you can use `animation`.

```
animation: spin 5s infinite;
```

"spin" is the name of the keyframes that define the motion.

```
@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotation(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotation(360deg); }
}
```